# Issue with Oracle Reports 6i to PDF

Tags: oracle, pdf, oraclereports

everyone.

I am working with Oracle Reports 6i to generate a report that includeds text in the form of paragraphs. Everything looks fine from the Real Time Viewer however when the report is run to generate a PDF, some, of the paragraphs would change from Justified to Filled.
This doesn't happen for every text container. In a full page I will have two paragraphs that are filled instead of justified.
Here is the details.

1. Each paragraph is within their own container.
2. The alignment for all containers is set to Justified(Flush)
3. Paragraphs have the same font type and font size.

I have already try the size of the output but it didn't make a difference. Is there any configuration parameter or any format function I can use to fix this?

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

If some paragraphs are OK and some are not, I'd suggest you to use good, old *copy/paste* principle:

- delete wrong ones
- copy correct one
- paste it
- edit its contents - hopefully, it'll look OK (as all properties the "correct" one had are now "inherited")